# OTSubscriber is not rendering in modal or previously hidden

Tags: react-native, opentok

Having issue with OTSubscriber.
Subscribe does not render inside the Modal but Publish is working fine as expected.

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import {OTSession, OTPublisher, OTSubscriber } from 'opentok-react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {            
        modalVisible: false
    }; 
}    
publishSubscribe = () => {
  this.setState({
    modalVisible: true
  })
}
render(){ 
    return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View>
              <Text>opentok session</Text>
              <Button  title="Publish + Subscribe" onPress={ () => this.publishSubscribe() }/>
            </View>                

            <OTSession 
                apiKey=''
                sessionId=''
                token='' 
                >    

                <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisible }>                                          
                    <OTPublisher style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
                    <OTSubscriber style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
                </Modal>

            </OTSession>  
        </View>
    );
}}
```

if  `modalVisible : true` set on constructor state, the modal popups on page load and both subscriber and publisher renders as expected.

Comment: No wonder it is rendered when the modal is visible. What is the problem?

Comment: subscriber  does not render when invoke manually.

Comment: found the problem. Subscriber is not streaming the already streamed stream in react native app. If I restart the streamer leaving the react native app as it is (modal opened), is starts streaming.